# How Limit Only 2 Rows To Show For Same Value In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct, limit

How to show all data but limit the same name value only 2 rows to show for example, here is my table 'test':

```
id  name
1   title-1
2   title-1
3   title-2
4   title-1
5   title-3
6   title-2
7   title-1
8   title-2
```

and i want the output to get all data, but limit only 2 rows to show if it's same name value, like this:

```
id  name
4   title-1
7   title-1
6   title-2
8   title-2
5   title-3
```

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.6

Comment: yap. i want get 2 rows for each value that have same name value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` in MySQL 8+:

```
select id, name
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where sequm <= 2;
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id >= coalesce( (select t2.id
                         from t t2
                         where t2.name = t.name
                         order by t2.id desc
                         limit 1, 1
                        ), t.id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e990d8dfb645a9436fe5de748e6d5577) is a db<>fiddle showing that this produces the desired results.

Comment: Any idea for MySQL 5.6?

Comment: It's return error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 1 limit 1
                  ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7

Comment: It's said: #1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea, does that mean your MySQL version IS actually MariaDB 10.0.

Comment: i've checked it, and it's said version 5.6

Comment: I'm sorry. it's work but the result is not what i want. i want to get all data but only show 2 rows for the multiple name value. it's show all data

Comment: actually this question still related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111348/how-limit-only-2-rows-to-show-for-same-value-in-mysql/

Comment: You are correct @DimasAdiAndrea . It is MySQL 5.6 engine. MariaDB is a basically MySQL but some operation are not the same (please correct me if I'm wrong ;). You can see from the Error message that you posted. Anyway, I've tested Gordon's solution and it does return exactly the same as your expected output. Only the ordering is not the same, which you can fix by adding `ORDER BY name` at the end.

Comment: @DimasAdiAndrea . . . It does not.  Both queries do what you want.  I've provided a SQL Fiddle with the data that you provide in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Must work.

```
SELECT name FROM test group by test having count(*) <= 2
```

Comment: Will return each name that exists at most twice. Not what OP is asking for.

Comment: That's exactly what he wants.

Comment: OP wants both rows, and also the id column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT name from (
SELECT name, row_number() over (partition by name) as RN from TEST group by test having count(Name) >= 1 ) a where RN <= 2
```